# Invalid Identifier Problem in my stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run below code but I am getting Invalid identifier 'RECORD.SALES_DATE'  error when I call the procedure.

Below is my query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_sales_and_logs()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
new_sales_table STRING := 'sales_new';
sales_table STRING := 'sales';
product_table STRING := 'products';
logs_table STRING := 'logs';
product_id NUMBER;
sales_date date;
product_exists NUMBER;
sales_record CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM sales_new;
BEGIN
FOR record IN sales_record DO
    product_id := record.product_id;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO product_exists FROM products WHERE products.product_id = product_id;

    IF (product_exists > 0)THEN
     INSERT INTO sales (sales_date, product_id, quantity, customer_id) 
     VALUES (record.sales_date, record.product_id, record.quantity, record.customer_id);

    ELSE
        INSERT INTO logs (sales_date, product_id, quantity, customer_id) 
        VALUES (record.sales_date, record.product_id, record.quantity, record.customer_id);
    END IF;
END FOR;
RETURN 'Procedure completed successfully.';
END;
```

Actually I have 4 tables named as sales_new, sales, products and logs. I just want to check for every record in the sales_new table that if the product_id from sales_new table is present in the products table then that record should be added to my existing sales table and if the product_id is not present in the products table then it should put that record in the logs table.

Comment: Hi  - can you update your question with the DDL for the sale_new table, please?

Answer (score 3):

In order to reference variable inside SQL statement they have to be prefixed with `:`

> [Using a Variable in a SQL Statement (Binding)¶](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding)
>
> **You can use a variable in a SQL statement.** (This is sometimes referred to as binding a variable.) **Prefix the variable name with a colon. For example:**
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO my_table (x) VALUES (:my_variable)
>                                  ^
> ```

---

The provided code sample does not use this syntax:

```
IF (product_exists > 0)THEN
 INSERT INTO sales (sales_date, product_id, quantity, customer_id) 
 VALUES (record.sales_date, record.product_id, record.quantity, record.customer_id);

ELSE
  INSERT INTO logs (sales_date, product_id, quantity, customer_id) 
  VALUES (record.sales_date, record.product_id, record.quantity, record.customer_id);
END IF;
```

Currently (version: 7.6.4) it is not possible to prefix For-Cursor loop variable and none of below versions will work:

- record.sales_date
- :record.sales_date
- record.:sales_date
- :record.:sales_date
- :(record.sales_date)

To reference the cursor variable you need to reassign it to helper variable(type has to be explicitly provided):

```
FOR record IN sales_record DO
    LET product_id INT   := record.product_id;
    LET sales_date DATE  := record.sales_date;
    LET quantity INT     := record.quantity;
    LET customer_id INT  := record.quantity;

    -- ... 
    INSERT INTO sales (sales_date, product_id, quantity, customer_id) 
    SELECT :sales_date, :product_id, :quantity, :customer_id;
 END FOR;
```

---

[Snowflake Ideas](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) - Search for:
"Direct for-cursor loop variable reference with SQL statements"

The idea is to allow syntax like: `:record.sales_date`