# How to use loop variables as bind variables Snowflake?

Tags: loops, reference, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, identifier, bind-variables

I want to use the row_variable from a for loop as a bind variable,

```
FOR <row_variable> IN <cursor_name> DO
    statement;
    [ statement; ... ]
END FOR [ <label> ] ;
```

```
DECLARE
    total_price FLOAT;
    c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM invoices;
    query VARCHAR DEFAULT 
'SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE price > ? AND price < ?';
BEGIN
    total_price := 0.0;
    OPEN c1;
    FOR rec IN c1 DO
        total_price := total_price + rec.price;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query USING (rec.price1, rec.price2))
    END FOR;
    CLOSE c1;
    RETURN total_price;
END;
```

The example above is made up only to highlight how I´d like to use the query **rec** is each of the rows of the resultset and **rec.column** would be a reference to one of those values,in this case **rec.price1** and **rec.price2**, but when I try to use it as a bind variable an error shows up (probably due to the ´´.´´ (dot) ).

I found a work around, which is assigning that ´´rec.column´´ value to a variable first and then using that as the bind variable, but that would mean creating a variable for each of the columns to use, which is not really ideal.

How can I reference these values directly as a bind variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Identifier Problem in my stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75644083/5070879).

 There is an open idea describing exactly this case.

[Snowflake Ideas](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) - Search for: **"Direct for-cursor loop variable reference with SQL statements"**